# Traits vs. Packages in Scala

Tags: scala, namespaces, package, traits

After watching [Martin's keynote on Reflection and Compilers](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2012/Reflection-and-Compilers) I can't seem to get this crazy question out of my head. Martin talks among other things about the "(Wedding) Cake Pattern", where traits play the central part. I'm wondering, why in the world do we need packages when we already have traits? Is there anything a `package` can do, what a `trait` (at least theoretically) cannot?

I'm not talking about the current implementation, I'm just trying to imagine what programming would be like if we replace packages with traits. In my head it would be like this:

- one keyword less (`package` is unneeded)
- no need for `package object`s

To summarize all my questions:

1. Is it theoretically possible to remove packages from the language and use traits instead.
2. What other benefits would we gain from this change? (I was thinking about first class packages and first class imports, but mixin composition is a compile time thing, although the super calls are dynamically bound)
3. Is Java/JVM compatibility the only thing, which would stand in the way?

**Update**

Daniel Spiewak talks in [this keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLbdw06tKPQ) about the Dependency Injection being just the top of the iceberg of all the stuff you can do with the Cake Pattern.

Comment: That's just (static) [newspeak](http://newspeaklanguage.org/)! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Martin Odersky has said that Scala could get by with just traits, objects, methods and paths (I hope I didn't forget something).

Both classes and packages are just there because Scala is intended to be a hosted language, i.e. a language which runs on (this is actually not the interesting bit) and *interoperates with* (this is the important point) a host platform. Some of the host platforms that Scala is intended to interoperate with are the Java platform and the CLI, both which have a concept of classes and packages (namespaces in the case of the CLI) that is significantly distinct enough that it cannot be easily expressed as traits or objects. This is unlike interfaces, which can be trivially mapped to and from purely abstract traits.

The above statement was made in a discussion about potentially removing generics from Scala, because everything generics can do can also be achieved by abstract types.

Comment: So you are saying it is actually theoretically possible, but would not be worth implementing it, because neither one of us is able to imagine what it would actually buy us ;)

Comment: It would buy a significant simplification of the language, and since simplicity is one Scala's main goals, it definitely makes sense. It would lose host platform interoperability, however, which is another main goal of Scala. You can use objects for all the cases where you would use packages, but there is no clean way to map Scala objects to Java packages or CLI namespaces. The situation with interfaces is different: there is an obvious mapping between fully abstract traits and interfaces, so, Scala can interoperate with Java/CLI interfaces without having them in the language.

Answer (score 6):

In scala the object and package serve almost the same purpose and objects are also called modules.  Objects deserve to be thought of as modules because they can contain any definition including other objects of course and, significantly, types.

A trait can be thought of as an abstract module.  It can contain any definition and any member can be abstract including, again significantly, type members.  I am reciting all this just to highlight the symmetry. Perhaps OT but to me traits seem to be as big an innovation in scala as the merging of object and functional ideas.

To finally give an answer:

1. I think packages could be removed in favour of objects (not traits).
2. The benefit would be a simplification - package objects would not need to be explicitly defined.
3. I think packages are distinct from objects for Java/JVM compatibility.

Some more commentary: in the video Martin talks of traits (abstract modules) more than concrete modules because the latter only appear at the last moment to assemble and reify some combination of abstract modules.

It is good to use abstract modules even when not "mixing a cake". e.g. when sketching out some code you might define a module to contain definitions.  But as soon as you come to a type or value you are not ready to fill in, don't supply a dummy such as null.  Instead switch the object to a trait and leave the member abstract.

Comment: What's "OT"? As a sidenote, there's a nice `???` function, which throws a `NotImplementedError` for implementations you're just not yet ready to write, and I believe it's much more convenient to use than performing any structural changes to your program.

Comment: Sorry, OT=off topic. Yep ??? is good for filling in values while "sketching" although not types.

Comment: Traits were invented well before Scala, http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Scha03aTraits.pdf